# Get Custom Property from Dynamic Module in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

How Can I get a custom Property like Title from a module I created in Module Builder?

I am using this method to retreive the module instance

```
 public static DynamicContent RetrievePollquestionByID(string guidID)
    {


        DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
        Type pollquestionType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Poll.Pollquestion");
        Guid pollquestionID = new Guid(guidID);


        DynamicContent pollquestionItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItem(pollquestionType, pollquestionID);
        return pollquestionItem;
```

I want to retreive the Title property of the DynamicContent.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model;` as a reference and then you will be able to use get and set methods. 
For example `pollquestionItem.GetValue("Title")`  and `pollquestionItem.SetValue("Title", "YourTitle")`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`pollquestionItem.GetValue<string>("Title")` or `pollquestionItem.GetValue("Title")`

You can see a complete code example through the sitefintiy UI.

**Administration >> Module Builder >> Pollquestion (the name of your Module) >> Code Reference**

Happy Coding This!

Comment: But GetValue is not a method of DynamicContent type. Not showing in intellisence.

Comment: Try adding this directive in your file: using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model;